# SyntaxError: invalid syntax inside map(lambda (x, y)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, functional-programming

This is the data in `time` column:

```
{'Thursday': {'0:00': 1, '23:00': 1, '21:00': 1}, 'Saturday': {'2:00': 1}, 'Monday': {'1:00': 1}}
```

But this code is giving me syntax error :

```
checkin_df['time_clean'] = map(lambda (x, y): map(lambda (k, v): map(lambda(i, value): [k, value, v.values()[i]], enumerate(v)), y.iteritems()), checkin_df['time'].iteritems())
```

I am getting the following error :

```
     checkin_df['time_clean'] = map(lambda (x, y): map(lambda (k, v): map(lambda(i, value): [k, value, v.values()[i]], enumerate(v)), y.iteritems()), checkin_df['time'].iteritems())
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which part am I missing ?
Could you please help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (removed parenthesis):

```
checkin_df['time_clean'] = map(lambda x, y: map(lambda k, v: map(lambda i, value: [k, value, v.values()[i]], enumerate(v)), y.iteritems()), checkin_df['time'].iteritems())
```